# Braintree custom fields - How to add product data

Tags: magento-1.9, api, payment-methods

I am using the **Gene Braintree** module on **Magento 1.9**, and I am trying to add some additional data points to the custom fields so I can reconcile the transactions.

I would like to pass **order#, product sku, and product description**.  Their is limited data available about which API names you would use to make this happen.

This article explains how to add the field in Braintree: https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/custom-fields

Thanks